# Как в ttk.combobox вывести определенное поле из массива, а получить другое?

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

Есть массив, полученный из БД *MSSQL*, например  из двух полей `id`, `name`:

```
name_list = [('1', 'Имя1'), (2, 'Имя2'), (3, 'Имя3'), (4, 'Имя4'), (5, 'Имя5')]
```

Завожу его в combobox, получаю `id`:

```
combobox_div = ttk.Combobox(frame, values=name_list)
print(name_list[combobox_div.current()][0])
```

Но! В списке combobox вижу все поля, типа:

```
1 Имя1
2 Имя2
...
```

Как выводить в список только

```
Имя1
Имя2
...
```

и возвращать те же `id`?